# Should I enable binlog binary logging on slave server?

Tags: mysql, replication

What are the benefits of enabling binary logging in MySQL slave server? I'm thinking that doing a switchover from master to slave and back to master would be easier in this way?

Answer (score 3):

That really depends on the size of your system and the level of automation you're using. What you can do with log_bin and log_slave_updates:

**1. Quick failover**

It's not hard job to find the most up-to-date slave promote and determine the position on the other slaves and point them to the new promoted master. There are tools to help your there.

Since MySQL 5.6 and the different flavours of it provides different implementation of GTID which makes it even less painful.

Without binlogs being enabled a restart is required which (again depending on your setup) can take significant time (hours even).

**2. Incremental backups and point in time recovery**

You can take a base backup of your slave with mysqldump, percona xtrabackup or any tool you prefer and make sure you don't run out of binlogs in case of a recovery you can just replay those logs.

**3. Analytical capabilities**

In case of statement based replication you can process those binlogs and gather useful statistics about which tables are the most written to, updated etc.

**+1 Scalability**

Once you reach that point you will already have the tools and configs for it but it worth to be mentioned: you can move your slave around easily, change the topology whenever you feel so.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling binary-logs on your current slave server will eliminate two steps of the failover process but there would still be many other steps involved.

In a true failover and depending on the scenario you'd probably go through the following steps.

1. Enable binary logs on the new master via my.cnf or equivalent.
2. Restart MySQL on the new master.
3. Grant the old master's replication user access to the
   new master.
4. Run the FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK command on the new master.
5. BACKUP the databases being replicated on the new master.
6. Run the UNLOCK TABLES command on the new master.
7. RESTORE those databases to the new slave.
8. Run the stop slave command on the current slave.
9. Run the CHANGE MASTER command on the old master to point to the new
   master.
10. Run START SLAVE on the new slave.

**Update after Karoly's comments**

As a follow response up to Karoly's answer and comments. If you really wanted to save time on the fail-over process, using a master-master replication schema would be the best idea in my opinion.

You would essentially prepare the slave to take over as master at anytime, leaving you with just redirecting your applications to the new master.

Assuming you've already setup a master-slave replication schema. 
The Basic steps to then setup a master-master replication, you would.

1. Turn on bin-logs on the slave
2. Turn on log-slave-updates on both the master and the slave
3. Configure the master to update from the slave with CHANGE MASTER
4. Grant access to the replication user on both master and slave
5. start slave on both servers
6. Eventually make the slave server read-only via the read-only my.cnf
   option

Comment: "Second, the binary logs are designed to record UPDATES/INSERTS/DELETES, i.e. data modification. If your slave server is not being updated in a master-master replication setup, then the binary logs won't be recording anything." - That's only true if log_slave_updates are turned off which would beat the purpose of what Mika is trying to achieve.

Comment: "So essentially with your idea, you are really not saving yourself a lot of time..." - Only true on small systems. Heavily written systems can take hours to do a clean MySQL restart. Also backup and restore can be done later online with percona xtrabackup for example.

Comment: Hello @KárolyNagy, I think some of what you said is true so I've updated my answer. Still I'm really doubtful that MySQL is supposed to take hours to do a clean startup no matter what the data volume involved. I'd like to see what someone like Rolando would say about that. Another thought is that your comments are a little confrontational. Please avoid that in the future as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Sorry Craig, I didn't mean to be confrontational.